# Numbers after url parameters in API ASP.NET and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, api

I created a Rest API and I call it from jquery like this :

```
$scope.apiCall = function (_type) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./handler/api.ashx/" + _type,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (datas, textStatus, xhr) {
            //my code
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

And my API is like this :

```
if (Request.RequestType == "GET")
    {
            string RawUrl = Request.RawUrl;
            string splitter = "api.ashx/";
            string SubRawUrl = RawUrl.Substring(RawUrl.IndexOf(splitter) + splitter.Length);               
            string[] Parameters = SubRawUrl.Split('/');

            if (Parameters.Length == 1 && Parameters[0] != "") 
            {
                //My Code
                Response.Write(resp.ToJSON());
                Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            }
    }
```

But in my API, the Request.RawUrl returns this :

```
/handler/api.ashx/Contact?_=1493885783112
```

Where "/Contact" is my "_type" parameter in $scope.apiCall function.

I checked, in debug mode, the result of "_type", it returned "Contact", so why I have " =1493885783112" in my URL?

Comment: Chrome. Before using $.ajax i used $.getJSON and it worked perfectly, without numbers, but i need to get back response and i didn't find how to do this with $.getJSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's added because you set `cache: false` in your `$.ajax()`-call.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
It adds the current timestamp ( in your case `1493885783112`) and prevents browsers from caching the request since each request will be unique .